# When not choosing a group of flags, get rid of the "All"

Tags: feature-request, flag-history, wording

Seeing all of our declined flags is one place is easy enough, just add "?status=3" to the URL of the flag history page (of course, this can apply to Helpful, pending, etc). However, this is what I currently see:

> [image]

Can the "All" be removed, so that it just says "Declined flags for..."?

Comment: Can you actually get to that page via the UI? Or did you just type in ?status=3? But either way `declined all flags` doesn't really make sense!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ haha, you got me. No direct link, but SE should know us better by now. (hence it's a feature request, not bug report :))